# Is there a CSS method/hack to specify a background color based on platform (ie. mac vs pc)

Tags: css, windows, macos, background-color

I keep running into a problem with designing websites on Mac. The colors I see on my laptop display invariably end up looking radically different when my clients view them on a PC. I've designed sites for clients who use both Mac and PC in their office environments so it's important that colors look similar (if not identical) no matter what computer they're using.

I know there are CSS hacks for browser specific properties .. but is there a way to change the background color on a website per which platform is being used by the viewer .. PC, Mac, etc.

I know this seems like a stretch since even identical platforms may be using different monitors, calibration etc. A shot in the dark but hoping there may be a creative answer!

Edit:
Here is how I've added the suggested script(s) to the head of the website .. my Javascript experience is so limited. I do have jquery ..

```
<script>
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

console.log('Your OS: '+OSName);
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
{
  $(body).css('background','#333');
} else {
  $(body).css('background','#000'); // this will style body for other OS (Linux/Mac)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aside from the answer below, probably also worth getting a cheap PC to test on - I saw a website that worked only on Webkit browsers the other day because the designer hadn't tested it outside of Safari - in IE it was just a blank screen!

Comment: I do have a pc laptop that I mainly use to bedug in IE since I don't like to run windows on my mac. One thing I've noticed it seems to be yellows and reds that have the most variance between mac and pc displays. Ugh

Comment: I have posted an answer to a similar question that shows what you can do (and what you cannot do) with straight CSS to target the OS based on specific browsers - with the exception of Chrome. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24218728/2246213

Answer (score 1):

Check this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494351/2307070)):

there is no property to specify OS used to view webpage, but you can detect it with javascript, here is some example for detecting Operating system :

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

console.log('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

got it?, now you can play with `document.write` to write download stylesheet for specific Operating system. :)

another example, i assumed that you are using jquery.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
{
  $(body).css('background','#333');
} else {
  $(body).css('background','#000'); // this will style body for other OS (Linux/Mac)
}
```

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!! I'm going to play with the above and see what I can come up with. I do prefer jquery to straight javascript but have used both. Funny .. I didn't even think about bringing that into the equation.

Comment: Ok my tiny bit of experience with javascript/jquery is showing .. I'm not doing something right. Are the two examples above stand alone or do they work together? I've tried plugging into the head section of a site and modifying the color codes for what I'm looking for and cannot tell that anything is changing. I enclosed the code above in the common <script></script> tags.

Comment: I added the code to the question .. I know it's probably very wrong syntax or missing something...?

Comment: @ToddDay first, I recommend you to take a free tour here http://www.w3schools.com/js/ , then try with this http://jsfiddle.net/